# At what time will a recurring payment trial end?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

If I create a recurring payment with a trial period of two weeks on:

```
7/24/13 at 7:35:00PM UTC
```

Will the trial period end (and the customer's payment method be charged) on:

```
8/7/13 at 7:35:00PM UTC
```

Or would the time (and possibly day, depending on the PayPal server time zone) be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time may fluctuate; the date is set and will run according to the PT timezone.
That's assuming that you have created a trial period which lasts a month, of course.